# Parsing XML in Android

Tags: android, xml, парсер, xmlparser

Необходимо распарсить [файл](https://github.com/osmandapp/OsmAnd-resources/blob/master/countries-info/regions.xml).

кусок xml:

```
<region type="continent" name="Europe"          translate="=Europe" inner_download_suffix="europe" boundary="no" poly_extract="europe">

<!-- north-europe -->
        <region name="denmark" lang="da" poly_extract="north-europe"/>
        <region name="estonia" lang="et" poly_extract="north-europe"/>
        <region name="iceland" lang="is" poly_extract="north-europe"/>
        <region name="faroe-islands" translate="Faroe Islands;entity=node" lang="fo" poly_extract="north-europe"/>
        <region name="finland" inner_download_prefix="$name" srtm="no" lang="fi,sv" poly_extract="north-europe">
            <region map="no" name="aland" translate="name:fi=Ahvenanmaa;admin_level=3;entity=relation"/>
            <region type="srtm" name="eastern-finland" translate="Eastern Finland;entity=relation"/>
            <region name="northern-finland" map="no" srtm="no" hillshade="no" wiki="no" translate="name:en=Northern Finland;entity=relation" boundary="no">
                <region type="srtm" name="lapland" translate="Lapland;entity=relation"/>
                <region type="srtm" name="northern-ostrobothnia" translate="name:en=Northern Ostrobothnia;entity=relation"/>
            </region>
            <region type="srtm" name="southern-finland" translate="Southern Finland;entity=relation"/>
            <region type="srtm" name="western-finland" translate="Western Finland;entity=relation"/>
        </region>
        <region name="latvia" lang="lv" poly_extract="north-europe"/>
        <region name="lithuania" lang="lt" poly_extract="north-europe"/>
        <region name="norway" srtm="no" inner_download_prefix="$name" lang="nb,nn" poly_extract="north-europe" join_map_files="yes">
            <region srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="akershus"/>
            <region srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="astfold" translate="Østfold;entity=node"/>
            <region srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="aust-agder"/>
            <region srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="buskerud"/>
            <region srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="finnmark"/>
            <region srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="hedmark"/>
            <region srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="hordaland"/>
            <region srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="more-og-romsdal" translate="Møre og Romsdal;entity=node"/>
            <region srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="nordland"/>
            <region srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="nord-trondelag" translate="Nord-Trøndelag;entity=node"/>
            <region srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="oppland"/>
            <region srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="oslo"/>
            <region srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="rogaland"/>
            <region srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="sogn-og-fjordane" translate="Sogn og Fjordane;entity=node"/>
            <region srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="sor-trondelag" translate="Sør-Trøndelag;entity=node"/>
            <region srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="telemark"/>
            <region srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="troms"/>
            <region srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="vest-agder"/>
            <region srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="vestfold"/>
            <region name="svalbard-and-jan-mayen" translate="Svalbard;entity=relation"/>
        </region>
        <region name="sweden" inner_download_prefix="$name" srtm="no" lang="sv" poly_extract="north-europe">
            <region map="yes" srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="blekinge" translate="Blekinge län;entity=relation"/>
            <region map="yes" srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="dalarna" translate="Dalecarlia;entity=relation"/>
            <region map="yes" srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="gavleborg" translate="Gävleborgs län;entity=relation"/>
            <region map="yes" srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="gotland" translate="Gotlands län;entity=relation"/>
            <region map="yes" srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="halland" translate="Hallands län;entity=relation"/>
            <region map="yes" srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="jamtland" translate="Jämtlands län;entity=relation"/>
            <region map="yes" srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="jonkoping" translate="Jönköpings län;entity=relation"/>
            <region map="yes" srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="kalmar" translate="Kalmar län;entity=relation"/>
            <region map="yes" srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="kronoberg" translate="Kronobergs län;entity=relation"/>
            <region map="yes" srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="norrbotten" translate="Norrbottens län;entity=relation"/>
            <region map="yes" srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="orebro" translate="Örebro län;entity=relation"/>
            <region map="yes" srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="ostergotland" translate="Östergötlands län;entity=relation"/>
            <region map="yes" srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="skane" translate="Skåne län;entity=relation"/>
            <region map="yes" srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="sodermanland" translate="Södermanlands län;entity=relation"/>
            <region map="yes" srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="stockholm" translate="Stockholms län;entity=relation"/>
            <region map="yes" srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="uppsala" translate="Uppsala län;entity=relation"/>
            <region map="yes" srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="varmland" translate="Värmlands län;entity=relation"/>
            <region map="yes" srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="vasterbotten" translate="Västerbottens län;entity=relation"/>
            <region map="yes" srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="vasternorrland" translate="Västernorrlands län;entity=relation"/>
            <region map="yes" srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="vastmanland" translate="Västmanlands län;entity=relation"/>
            <region map="yes" srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="vastra-gotaland" translate="Västra Götalands län;entity=relation"/>
        </region>
```

Разметку менять нельзя.
Добыть названия "continent" у меня не возникло проблем. Но вот получить имена стран внутри определенного континента  я не могу - получаю только первую страну

```
    try {
        XmlPullParser xpp =getResources().getXml(R.xml.regions);

        while (xpp.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            switch (xpp.getEventType()) {
                // начало документа
                case XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT:
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "START_DOCUMENT");
                    break;
                // начало тэга
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                    for (int i = 0; i < xpp.getAttributeCount(); i++) {
                        if (xpp.getAttributeValue(i).equals(id)) {
                            for (int j = 0; j < xpp.getAttributeCount(); j++) {
                                if( xpp.getAttributeName(j).equals("name"))
                                {
                                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "COUNTRY="+xpp.getAttributeValue(j));
                                    xpp.next();
                                    if ((xpp.getAttributeName(0).equals("name")||xpp.getAttributeName(1).equals("name"))

                                            ) {
                                        Log.d("Region", "1="+ xpp.getAttributeValue(0));
                                        //получаю имя первой страны и добавляю в RecycleView
                                        count.add(new Country(xpp.getAttributeValue(0)));

                                        xpp.next();
                                       break;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                // конец тэга
                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                   /* for (int i = 0; i < xpp.getAttributeCount(); i++) {
                         Log.d("END ATRIBUTTE", "VALUE="+xpp.getAttributeValue(i)+" NAME="+ xpp.getAttributeName(i));
                        }*/

                    break;
                // содержимое тэга
                case XmlPullParser.TEXT:

                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
            // следующий элемент
            xpp.next();
        }
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "END_DOCUMENT");

    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Распарсил. Использовал как пример азию:

```
 try {
        XmlPullParser xpp =getResources().getXml(R.xml.regions);
        while (xpp.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            switch (xpp.getEventType()) {
                // начало документа
                case XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT:
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "START_DOCUMENT");
                    break;
                // начало тэга
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:

                    for (int i = 0; i < xpp.getAttributeCount(); i++) {

                        if (xpp.getAttributeValue(i).equals("asia")) {
                            for (int j = 0; j < xpp.getAttributeCount(); j++) {
                                if( xpp.getAttributeName(j).equals("name"))
                                {

                                  xpp.next();

                                  while ((xpp.getEventType() == XmlPullParser.START_TAG)&&
                                      !(xpp.getAttributeValue(0).equals("continent"))) {
                                   if ((xpp.getAttributeName(0).equals("name")
                                           ||xpp.getAttributeName(1).equals("name"))) {
                                        map=true;
                                       for(int x = 0; x < xpp.getAttributeCount(); x++){

                                           if (xpp.getAttributeName(x).equals("map")) {
                                               switch (xpp.getAttributeValue(x)){
                                                   case "no":
                                                       map = false;
                                                       break;
                                                   default:
                                                       break;
                                               }

                                           }

                                       }
                                       Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Country="+xpp.getAttributeValue(0));
                                       Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Map="+map);
                                       count.add(new Country(firstUpperCase(xpp.getAttributeValue(0)),map,download,id));
                                        xpp.next();
                                       while(xpp.getDepth()>3){
                                           xpp.next();
                                       }
                                    }
                                      xpp.next();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    break;
                // конец тэга
                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:

                    break;
                // содержимое тэга
                case XmlPullParser.TEXT:

                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
            // следующий элемент
            xpp.next();
        }
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "END_DOCUMENT");

    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```